# Block specific http request from windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, http, blocking

How can i block certain requests from all applications based on pattern?

Eg. lets say i doesn't want my computer to access `example.com/example.php`, not the whole domain.

I'm running windows 7

Comment: Maybe an antivirus software can do that. You could also set up a proxy, either on your PC or on a separate computer, configure it to block certain http patterns, and configure Windows 7 to use it.

Comment: That is actually great idea :)

Comment: Thanks, I think Squid and SOCKS can do that, the actual installation and implementation may be tricky, though.